# Silverlight Client not installed for project in Test Environment

Tags: silverlight, iis

After deploying a Silverlight project to our test server, I get prompted to install the plugin,  which I already have installed. Doesn't do this on the dev server, though I can download the file fine from the test server.

Could this be a mime type issue?

This is also the first Silverlight app we have created, so it's not as if there are other projects on the test box that are working...

Answer (score 0):

you should check your version numbers. this is the most common solution with this error.
[here is a site](http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2010/04/determining-silverlight-version-installed) with some scripts to help you determine what version you have installed.

in the `<object>` tag on your aspx (or html,whatever) page, check the minRuntimeVersion

`<param>` this is the expected minimum version to run the silverlight app. if sl detects an earlier version , you get the whole "silverlight is not installed" message

Comment: what do you mean version numbers? silverlight version?

Comment: yes! if SL detects an earlier version then what it is expecting, you get the "silverlight is not installed" message.